# Email-based FaceTime on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, facetime, apple-id

The new iPod Touch and the Mac FaceTime app both allow the user to send and receive FaceTime calls with their email address/Apple ID as the identifier. Is it possible to set up an iPhone 4 to send/receive FaceTime calls with my email address instead of my phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following why everyone else is saying this can't be done.  I have people facetime me all the time on my phone, by using my AppleID email address.  I also contact others this same way, and it works just fine.  In fact it has the added bonus of ringing ALL iDevices linked to that address.  So when someone facetimes my AppleID, it rings on my iPhone, Mac, and iPad all at the same time, allowing me to answer it wherever I am at that moment.

I didn't do anything special to set this up... just went into FaceTime under Settings, and added the email address(es) I wanted people to be able to reach me on.  Works fine.

Maybe this is specifically a problem on the iPhone 4 as opposed to the 4s which is what I have?

Comment: You're right, the other answers here are out of date. Email-based FaceTime for iPhone was added in iOS 5.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose I could have looked at the date of those answers eh?  8)  Oh well, maybe my comment will help someone else in the future anyway.

Answer (score 4):

On the iPhone itself, you are unable to add "e-mail address aliases" like in the OSX App. The only method of having people call your iPhone is by giving them your phone number.

As far as the iPhone making facetime calls, the only easy way I've seen to do it is to already have their Facetime address in your Address Book, or use Safari.

Open Safari on your iPhone, go to the URL bar, type: `<facetime://their@email.addr>`, then tap the "Facetime" acknowledgement button afterwards.

Comment: I seem to recall reading something about creating a Facetime Contact Bookmark, which should be the easy part, but I seem to also remember reading something about a Home Screen Facetime Contact link, which I can't seem to find or put together how to do yet.

Comment: P.S. I have 4.2 on my iPad and iPhone, so I know also that nothing's changing 4.1 -> 4.2 to make this process easier, which I'm very disappointed to say.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for the tip about Safari, though. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think email address is the only way to do it.

Comment: On the iPhone 4, it's based off of the phone number, and I want to use my email instead like on the iPod Touch/Mac FaceTime app

Comment: sorry i was confused. Please don't do minuus!